# Reading large set of integers into array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file containing about 10^7 space separated integers in a single line, each consisting of about 8 digits. When I try to read this into an array **s** using the usual **map()** and **raw_input.split()** in this way,

```
s = map(long,raw_input().split( ))
```

I get a runtime error. Is this due to the way in which input is read from the file or because of the array size becoming too large? In either case, what can be done to overcome this?

Comment: What specific 'runtime error' do you get?

Comment: way are you using `raw_input` for reading a file?

Comment: @acushner Maybe OP's solving some programming problem in Online Judges. In those, the I/O is generally redirected to standard input and standard output.

Comment: I tried reading a file with `10^7` integers of 8 digits (specifically this number `12345678`) and it worked in my local machine. If OP is solving this in an Online Judge then this might happen because of memory constraints. It'll be good if OP would provide some more information on this.

Comment: Yes I am using an Online Judge. Specifically, Hackerrank!

Comment: @samurdhilbk Can you provide some more information? Because otherwise it'll be difficult to say why you are getting Runtime Error.